# HasMentionPrefix not working when launching the bot with Linux, but working when launching on Windows

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm developing my C# bot with the discord.Net libraries and I figured out that, when I'm launching the bot under Linux (Debian 4.9.144-3.1) (with mono), the bot does not respond to a command when mentioning him and putting the command after. But does work when launched on my windows 10 computer. If anyone know why and how to resolve this issue

Discord.NET version : 2.0.1
Debian version : Debian 4.9.144-3.1
Windows 10 version : 17763.437

I've tried to fallback to Discord.NET 2.0.0 but, the issue stay the same

```cs
            var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(DiscordClient, message);
            var prefixPos = 0;
            if (message.HasStringPrefix("b!", ref prefixPos) ||
                  message.HasMentionPrefix(DiscordClient.CurrentUser, ref prefixPos))
            {
                var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, prefixPos, null);
                if (!result.IsSuccess)
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"[Erreur] : à {DateTime.Now}, une erreur s'est produite avec la commande {context.Message.Content} | Stracktrace : {result.ErrorReason}");
            }
```

I expected the bot to respond

Answer (score 0):

In the Discord.Net documentation, it is explicitly mentioned that [Mono is not supported](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/getting_started/installing.html?tabs=vs-install%2Ccore2-1#supported-platforms). Using Mono or non-Core runtime may lead to unexpected behaviour. Switch to .NET Core instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did not checked out, will read next time